# How to convert this into the proper date format?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I currently have a have a date in the form of a varchar (dddyyyy, ddyyyy or dyyyy) and I need to convert it into a date (rounded to the nearest weak nonetheless). The problem is: when I execute what I came up with thus far (as shown below) I receive dates in the format of '00:00:00 01/23/2017'. Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT distinct trunc(to_date(lpad(date, 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY'), 'iw') as week
  FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Is the date you get wrong, or is your client just displaying it in a way you didn't expect? Dates don't have any intrinsic format; so you may just need to add a `to_char()` wrapper to get it back as a string in the format you want, but it isn't clear.

Comment: where is month in your format??

Comment: Could you show some input values and their expected output? Is this a Julian date format ("day-of-year")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to round it of to nearest week use this:

```
select next_day('14-09-2018', 'SUNDAY') from dual;
```